# How to reference views programmatically without using IBOutlet

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS programming and I am working with XCode learning storyboards. My question is

I have added the views that I want using the IB but I dont want to them to connect to my ViewController using Ctrl+Drag in the IB but do the same programmatically.
I have seens posts suggesting to create instances of the views in code and add them (by setting frame) using addSubView(). But I dont want to hardcode my frame and sizes in code, I prefer IB for that. I only need to refer to them when I need.

In android, we can do the same by getIdByName() on the layout XML. I am looking for something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In IB you can set the `Tag` property of the view and then reference it in code by using:

```
int buttonTagNumber = 2;
UIButton *myTaggedButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonTagNumber];
```

Tags are just an `int`, you can have as many of them as you like. Note that if you have the same tag on 2 different views within one heirarchy, the behaviour is undefined and it will grab the first one of these it finds.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But I still need to have a IBOutlet defined in my ViewController.h. If I remove it I get [<ViewController setValue:forUndefinedKey:]; error

Comment: Ah, you need to go into Interface Builder and remove the connection you may have made to an outlet. Just click the cross next to the outlet name and clear the connection, then you can remove the outlet without getting key-value coding compliance errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could drilldown like this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
    UIView *view = [vc.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: Hi, your answer holds good if you need to refer the viewcontroller in the storyboard. This is not what I want, I need to refer to the views already in the viewcontroller.

Comment: then the viewWithTag option might be the solution for you